# SendKeys Page Down not working Python

Tags: python, sendkeys

I am trying to move my mouse, click on a specific form and then page down. The SendKeys is not working for Page Down but works fine for Enter, any ideas?

```
import win32api, win32con
import win32com.client

def test():           
    win32api.SetCursorPos((950,405))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,950,405,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,950,405,0,0)
    shell.SendKeys("{PGDN}", 0)

test()
```

Comment: Your code misses `shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")`

Comment: Yup that works, why is it only required for PGDN?

Comment: You refer a `shell` variable which isn't defined. Python doesn't know what it should be if you don't tell it. In general, try to run Python scripts on Windows first with `python.exe` in a console, not `pythonw.exe` to see error messages (which had told you about the problem).